# latest yum/dnf packages not showing on RHEL 8

Tags: rhel, yum, dnf

We have several RHEL 8.8 instances in AWS which have the BaseOS and AppStream RHUI repositories available. However, we cannot see updated versions of several packages which were flagged in a recent Nessus scan - one example would be the 8.9 kernel, 4.18.0-513.5.1.el8_9, though there are a variety of other packages as well which should be available according to the related RHSAs.

The repositories are available, reachable, and browsable after cleaning the dnf cache. There are no errors. I've read that it's not possible to update RHEL systems without an active subscription but we've been installing packages from these repositories without RHSM with no issues for several months (and for several years before that on RHEL 7), so I'm not sure what the deal is there. This is a very recent issue so if it is related to subscriptions, I don't know what could have suddenly changed.

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: As the version tag `el8_9` indicates, the kernel version 4.18.0-513.5.1.el8_9 is part of minor release 8.9 of RHEL 8. If your systems include some third-party software that depends specifically on minor release being 8.8, it might block the automatic upgrade from 8.8 to 8.9 until the third-party software itself is upgraded. Or if you don't have a RedHat Subscription of your own, you might be accessing some AWS-managed mirror repository and paying for it as part of the AWS payments - in which case you should be asking AWS support about what's going on with the repository.

Comment: However, since RHEL 8.9 was released just 2 weeks ago, it might be as simple as AWS not releasing 8.9 to their update repository until they've verified that all their cloud management tools work 100% with it. Or maybe you must do something in AWS management interface to authorize the upgrade to a higher minor release (effectively switching from a 8.8 repository to a 8.9 one)? I don't know, I've not used AWS myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When connected to RHUI, you don't manage subscriptions.  The system just sees normal RPM repositories.

You stated that you are using RHEL 8.8, but can't see an 8.9 kernel.  It is possible that your instance is locked to 8.8.  This is typically done client side by setting a value in `/etc/dnf/vars/releasever`.  If that file doesn't exist, then it's possible the RHUI repos you're pointing to are being limited to 8.8 content.  You can check this by running `dnf list --available --showduplicates redhat-release` and verifying that an 8.9 version of that package is available.  Your cloud provider may have other images available that default to all RHEL 8 content, rather than just RHEL 8.8 content.

Comment: Yeah, /etc/yum/vars/releasever was the issue - figured it out with AWS support a bit ago. It was surprising since this file was not created by us or otherwise modified by us, so we're not sure how it was set and did not consider it initially.

Thanks for the response.